# Call a javascript function with parameters from within a package.json script

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

A javascript file foo.js has the following content:

```
function foo(param){
    console.log('foo called with params');
    console.log(param);
}
module.exports.foo = foo;
```

How can I call this function from within a package.json script?

```
"scripts": {
        "foo": "node foo.js foo(1)", 
    },
```

Just returns

> node foo.js foo(1)

I.e., the function is not invoked.

Comment: node -e 'require("./foo.js").foo(1)'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command `node foo.js foo(1)` does not run even if you don't put it inside an npm script:

- Don't wrap your code inside a function if you wish to execute it from the command line
- use `process.argv[2]` to capture args from the command

Which means that your `foo.js` script should look like:

```
console.log('generateI18 is with param');
console.log(process.argv[2]);
```

(no need to export anything)

And you can execute it as:

```
node foo.js 1
```

You can then add it to your npm scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "foo": "node foo.js 1", 
},
```

and run it:

```
npm run foo
```