# With Node ES6 how to run export default from package.json script?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, async-await, default, package.json

Given a file named *weekday.js* in my `src` directory of:

```
#! /usr/bin/env node

export const mon = () => console.log('Monday')

export const tues = () => console.log('Tuesday')

export const wed = () => console.log('Wednesday')

export default async () => {
  await mon()
  await tues()
  await wed()
}
```

and in *package.json* scripts of:

```
"type": "module",
"scripts": {
  "week": "node src/weekday.js"
},
```

how should the file be called when the command of:

```
npm run week
```

does not log anything to the console and I've also tried:

```
"node -e 'import(\"./src/weekday.js\")'"
```

In my research all I am finding is about the addition of `module`:

- [Using Node.js require vs. ES6 import/export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export)
- [Production script in package.json cant find a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68653723/production-script-in-package-json-cant-find-a-module)
- [Should core Node modules be listed in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68261362/should-core-node-modules-be-listed-in-package-json)
- [Call a javascript function with parameters from within a package.json script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48396596/call-a-javascript-function-with-parameters-from-within-a-package-json-script)
- [Call a nested package.json script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67681314/call-a-nested-package-json-script)

How should an export default be called in package.json's scripts?

### Edit

Per the comment of:

> Try to execute the function as a normal function: "node -e
> 'require("./src/weekday.js")();'"

throws the terminal error:

> Must use import to load ES Module

so tried:

```
"scripts": {
    "weekday": "node -e 'import(\"./src/weekday.js\")()'"
  },
```

but throws error:

```
[eval]:1
import("./src/weekday.js")()
                              ^
TypeError: ImportCall("./src/weekday.js") is not a function
```

Comment: Try to execute the function as a normal function: "node -e 'require(\"./src/weekday.js\")();'"

Comment: @hoangdv that throws the error `Must use import to load ES Module`

Comment: The async/await doesn't seem to make sense in your example

Comment: Why did you put the functionality inside a (default-exported) function instead of just running the code, if your *weekday.js* is meant to be a cli script? Why do you `export` stuff at all, is there a module that imports these things?